# JQuery .html() not returning result of get() from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, fiddler

I've got a page with four divs on it that I'm trying to load using jquery. The user shows and hides the divs by clicking on links. Currently, the contents of the divs are populated with PHP include statements, but that leads to ~30-second load times for the page.

I'm trying to replace those include statements with JQuery in order to load the proper contents of each div when the user clicks the link to show or hide it. My problem is that when I click one of the links to switch divs, the div appears but without anything in it. I've used Fiddler to ensure the request is going off (which it is) but the response is coming back as a 404.

However, when I examine the response in Fiddler, the expected HTML is there, just not getting passed into my element properly. I've tried using .load() as well as $.get(), but got the same results. I've also ensured my element names are correct as well. Code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {  
$('#allvideos').click(function () {
    $.get("/wp-content/themes/Danceamatic/templates/all_videos.php", function(data) {
        var $resp = data;
        $( "#carrusel_all_videos" ).html($resp);
        alert("Load was performed.");
    });
    $('#current_showcase').hide();
    $('#carrusel_new_videos').hide(); 
    $('#carrusel_featured').hide(); 
    $('#carrusel_all_videos').show();
    $('#i_mentors').hide();         
    return false;
});

$('#featuredvideos').click(function () {
    $.get("/wp-content/themes/Danceamatic/templates/view_featured.php", function(data) {
        var $resp = data;
        $( "#carrusel_featured" ).html($resp);
        alert("Load was performed.");
    }); 
    $('#current_showcase').hide(); 
    $('#carrusel_all_videos').hide(); 
    $('#carrusel_new_videos').hide(); 
    $('#carrusel_featured').show();
    $('#i_mentors').hide();     
    return false;   
});
$('#newvideos').click(function () {
    $.get( "/wp-content/themes/Danceamatic/templates/new_videos.php", function( data ) {
        $( "#carrusel_new_videos" ).html( $.parseHTML(data) );
        alert( "Load was performed." );         
    });
    $('#current_showcase').hide(); 
    $('#carrusel_all_videos').hide(); 
    $('#carrusel_featured').hide(); 
    $('#carrusel_new_videos').show();
    $('#i_mentors').hide(); 
    return false;
}); 
$('#currentshowcase').click(function () {
    $('#carrusel_all_videos').hide(); 
    $('#carrusel_new_videos').hide();   
    $('#carrusel_featured').hide(); 
    $('#current_showcase').show();
    $('#i_mentors').show();
  });   
});
```

I've set breakpoints on the `"var $resp = $data"` line and have not hit it at all.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try `$( "#carrusel_all_videos" ).html(data);` ...also print the output of `console.log(data);`

Comment: If you're getting a 404 error code, jQuery doesn't go into the callback function. You need to use `.error()` to pick up this response. You need to figure out why the server is sending back an error code along with the response.

Comment: @RobertRozas I've already used that as well, that's what I started with. Using $resp was a way to have somewhere to set a breakpoint and check the response.

Comment: @KyleCritchnau, i can't see the output of `console.log(data);` anywhere....

Comment: I meant doing $( "#carrusel_all_videos" ).html(data); I'll do that as well and post it. One moment.

Comment: I've gotten the allvideos working. Featured is still giving me problems, and data is empty on that one. Not sure why, I suspect it's got something to do with the view_featured.php file not evaluating correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The url `"/wp-content/themes/Danceamatic/templates/all_videos.php"` is not correct. Double check the location of the javascript file that makes this request and also check the location of the php file.

If the location seems correct then maybe it's the structure of the url -- try:

`"wp-content/themes/Danceamatic/templates/all_videos.php"` or

`"./wp-content/themes/Danceamatic/templates/all_videos.php"` or

`"../wp-content/themes/Danceamatic/templates/all_videos.php"`.

Comment: After some more digging, the files in question (all_videos.php, view_featured.php, and new_videos.php) are in the same folder as the file that is calling this function. Using ./all_videos.php doesn't work, neither does all_videos.php.